# Is it safe to delete a key/value pair from a CAtlMap during iteration?

Tags: c++, winapi, atl

I apologize, but I haven't come across an answer.  When iterating over a [`CAtlMap`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/atl/reference/catlmap-class?view=msvc-160) like so:

```
POSITION pos = map.GetStartPosition();
while (pos != NULL) 
{
   key = map.GetKeyAt(pos);
   value = map.GetNextValue(pos);
   //...
}
```

is it safe to perform deletions using [`CAtlMap::RemoveKey`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/atl/reference/catlmap-class?view=msvc-160#removekey) and to keep iterating?

Comment: Thanks, but do you think `CAtlMap::RemoveKey` might behave differently than `CAtlList::RemoveAt`?  My question concerns the map class, rather than the list class.

Comment: Why would it?  If `RemoveAtPos` doesn't invalidate `POSITION`s to other elements, there's no reason why `RemoveKey` should.

Comment: It is, in general, never safe to modify a container while you're iterating through it.